# Square brackets in the id name of an input by browser (dusk) test

Tags: laravel

I have a problem. When I use the Laravel browser test, I usually testing the date fields with this:

```
->script([
     "document.querySelector('#date_of_show').value = '2019-01-01'",
  ]);
```

It works. But when the name of id contains square brackets, the selector does not find it. Example:

```
->script([
     "document.querySelector('#items[0][date_of_show]').value = '2019-01-01'",
  ]);
```

I have trying a lot of style, but I can not solve it.
Can someone help me?

Thanks,

update :
the browser method:

```
$this->browse(function(Browser $browser) use ($user, $buyer, $buyerSearch) {
        $browser
            ->loginAs($user)
            ->visit(route('buyer-search-properties.index', [$buyer, $buyerSearch]))
            ->check('items[0][check]')
            ->select('action', 'fixing-show')
            ->waitForText('Fixing Shows')
            ->script([
                "document.querySelector('#items\\[0\\]\\[date_of_show\\]').value = '2019-01-01'",
            ]);
        $browser
            ->click('Create');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets. Could you give this a try?

```
->script([
     "document.querySelector("#items\\[0\\]\\[date_of_show\\]").value = '2019-01-01'",
  ]);
```

Edit: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv3bunpf/) to show this in action.

Edit: I might be missing something, but would the following work?

```
$browser
    ->loginAs($user)
    ->visit(route('buyer-search-properties.index', [$buyer, $buyerSearch]))
    ->check('items[0][check]')
    ->select('action', 'fixing-show')
    ->waitForText('Fixing Shows')
    ->value('#items\\[0\\]\\[date_of_show\\]', '2019-01-01');
```

Comment: Gave it a try on my local and seems to be working fine. Just to be clear, you have an element that has an attribute as such: `id="items[0][id]"`, right?

Comment: In the browser the element:

`<input type="date" id="items[0][date_of_show]" name="items[0][date_of_show]" value="" class="rounded-sm bg-white rounded-md border text-sm font-light text-grey-darker py-1 px-3 w-full">`

in the test:
     `->script([
           "document.querySelector('#items\\[0\\]\\[date_of_show\\]').value = '2019-01-01'",
     ]);`

The error message:
invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#items[0][date_of_show]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: You should replace `id` with `date_of_show`. Edited and also added a fiddle to show you a working example :)

Comment: Ok. I changed they.

Comment: Ok. It work in fiddle, but id does not work in dusk test :( What is the problem??? :(

Comment: Can I see the full test method?

Comment: I think is the point the 'is not a valid selector' in the error message...
Maybe the square bracket is not allowed in the Laravel dusk scripts. If I pull out they, it works fine. Example: change `'items[0][date_of_show]'` with simple `'date_of_show'` ...

Comment: I add the browse method for the origin question.

Comment: Edited my answer. Could you give it a try?

Comment: No. I don't want an assert, I want to set the date field value.

Comment: Could you post the answer for others as well?

Answer (score 0):

I solved! It works!

```
->script([
      "document.querySelector('[name=\"items[0][date_of_show]\"]').value = '2018-12-20'",
     ]);
```